# Highlight an individual character of text block containing links and heading on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to achieve that when hovering over a character, the character should change color. It should work on individual characters, links, headings etc.

My following code gives me result that I want but it removes the links and headings.

```js
$cont = $('.words');
parts = $.map($cont.text().split(''), function(v) {
  return $('<span />', {
    text: v
  });
});
$cont.empty().append(parts);
```

```css
.words span:hover {
  color: #F00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="words">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  <a href="#link">LINK</a>
  <h1>
    Heading
  </h1>
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus e Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/bvpodc6z/1/

Comment: you're taking all the text inside the element. that won't take into account the html.

Comment: Consider upgrading your jQuery version. 1.10.1 is almost 9 years old. 3.6.0 is the latest, as of this comment.

Comment: This code works fine. But it convert all the html into span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map the characters separately for each text node so that it doesn't erase your DOM structure.

```js
$('.words, .words *').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
      $(this).replaceWith(escapeHTML(this.nodeValue).split('').map(c => `<span>${c}</span>`).join(''));
});

function escapeHTML(s) {
  return s.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
          .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
          .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
          .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
          .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as i want it. You are the gem.

Comment: I updated the ***JS Fiddle*** if any one need. http://jsfiddle.net/7ywohnqr/

Answer (score 0):

Had to make some slight changes to html, namely adding a p tag around text thats not in heading or link : http://jsfiddle.net/kfbaz3gw/

```
$('.words').children().each( (index, el) => {
    $(el).html(function (i, html) {
      var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
      return  chars.map(c=>'<span>'+c+'</span>').join('')
  });
 })
```